# Yii2 Create Pretty URL like /index.php/viewName/actionName/var1/value1/var2/value2

Tags: php, url, routes, yii2

i am playing around with yii2 (recently been working in Yii 1.3) and need help to configure/write the Url-Manager Rules for my favorite URL-sheme.

As Example, i wanna call the action `test` from `xmpleController` with 2 parameters.

a normal GET request would looks like this:

`?param1=value1&param2=value2`

at the moment, my url look like this:

`index.php/xmple/test/?param1=value1&param2=value2`

This is how the url should look like:

`index.php/xmple/test/param1/value1/param2/value2`

here are my URL-Manager Rules:

```
'urlManager' => [
     'enablePrettyUrl' => True,
     'showScriptName' => false,
     'rules' => [
        '<a:\w+>/<b:\w+>/<c:\d+>/<d:\d+>' => 'a/b'
     ],
 ],
```

Does anybody have an Idea how I can use my favorite URL scheme? I think the only way to reach my goal is to edit the urlManager rule, but I don't have any experience in this. maybe someone here has some hint for me?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? or still need help.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start making your desired URL format you need to understand first what formats are supported by the URL manager when working in Yii2. And how to create rules to create those formats.

### Supported URL Formats

- #### The default URL format;

  The default URL format uses a query parameter named `r` to represent the route and normal query parameters to represent the query parameters associated with the route. The URL `/index.php?r=xmple/test&param1=100` represents the route `xmple/test` and the `param1` query parameter `100`. The default URL format does not require any configuration of the URL manager and works in any Web server setup.
- #### The pretty URL format.

  Uses the extra path following the entry script name to represent the route and the associated query parameters. For example, the extra path in the URL `/index.php/xmple/100` is `/xmple/100` which **may** represent the route `xmple/test` and the `param1` query parameter `100` with a proper URL rule. To use the pretty URL format, you will need to design a set of URL rules according to the actual requirement about how the URLs should look like.

  This rule can satisfy the above statement `'xmple/<param1:\d+>' => 'xmple/test',`

[Read More](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#url-formats) about it here

So it is not going to be showing

`index.php/xmple/test/param1/value1/param2/value2` but

`index.php/xmple/test/value1/value2` or `index.php/xmple/value1/value2` or `xmple/test/value1/value2`.

### How to create Rules

You can configure [`yii\web\UrlManager::$rules`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager#$rules-detail) as an array with keys being the [patterns](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlrule#$pattern-detail) and values the corresponding [routes](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlrule#$route-detail).

[Read More](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#url-rules) here

You can use the rule `'xmple/test/<param1:\w+>/<param2:\w+>'=>'xmple/test'` considering that you will be sending parameters that match any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_])` as a parameter, which will output `xmple/test/value1/value2` with `'showScriptName' => false,` or `index.php/xmple/test/value1/value2` otherwise.

If the rule is going to be used for a single controller/action or you can use as described or use the [parameterized routes](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#parameterizing-routes) which allows a URL rule to be used for matching multiple routes.

You can change your urlManager to the following

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
             'xmple/test/<param1:\w+>/<param2:\w+>'=>'xmple/test'
        ],
 ],
```